# What exactly am I supposed to see at the end of "The Car" (1977)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-car

After the evil car falls down the cliff and dynamite is applied, the
deputies are gazing in horror at the following apparition (1:11 onward) :

I mean, it is supposed to be really, really scary. Not that it is really scary with the bad, cheesy overacting, but it is supposed to be scary.

Erm...

**What exactly am I supposed to see?**

Wikipedia tells me ["a monstrous demonic visage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Car). *I* only see black smoke and a firewand and horrific classic music. Could be that I flunked at Rohrschach inkblots, I don't see anything remotely terrific.

Could someone show me in a still image what is supposed to be scary and where the demonic visage is?

Comment: Just for curiosity, the classical music alluded in the staccato is the theme of the original *[Dies Irae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dies_irae#Music)*.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Could someone show me in a still image what is supposed to be scary and where the demonic visage is?

## Sure.

[image]

> I mean, it is supposed to be really, really scary. Not that it is really scary with the bad, cheesy overacting, but it is supposed to be scary.

Well that's a matter of interpretation and wholly subjective. Perhaps it was *really scary* in 1977 but 40 years have gone by and we've seen a lot more stuff since then.

Comment: This holds for exactly a whole millisecond and the result is a smiling smoke kermit with a butterfly on his eyes?

Comment: In the above video, pause about 1:26 and you'll also see the hand/claw.

Comment: Yeah. 1:25 is where you can see the claw. 1:35 you can see a face form and a tongue come out of its mouth.

Comment: @SliderBlackrose *Now* that you say it, yes, the flaming debris I saw looks really like a hand/claw...